# Help finding PWM IC with marking on device 'FA=606'. Package of device is SOT23 - 6

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, pwm, identification

I found this 6 pin PWM IC in one of the SMPS. I am unable to find any of its details on Google. I am requesting if anyone could help me finding the device name. The marking is something like **FA=606** or **1FA=606**.

[image: Photo of PCB showing unknown device]

Comment: Details on what is connected to each pin would be helpful.

Comment: PIN  1 - GND, 2 - FB, 3 - NC, 4 - SENSE, 5 - VCC, 6 - GATE

Comment: FA could be a former Fairchild reference like a FAN 60x but I could not find a reference corresponding to your marking. The pinout you describe is however common to many TSOP-6 PWM components. The [NCP1253](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCP1253-D.PDF) could certainly do the job if you're looking for a low-voltage die.

Comment: please post full pics of your smps circuit front or back both and define In put and out put voltage marking of some common parts detail driver transit BJT or FET Wich use we will try to inditify and other short cut for your Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR;** It's likely a Richtek [R7735GGE](https://www.richtek.com/Products/AC_DC/Flyback%20Controller/R7735?sc_lang=en&specid=R7735) PWM flyback controller.

---

There are many controllers in this format all with the same package (SOT23-6) and similar pinouts, so it's hard to narrow down the exact ones. So a bit of sleuthing was in order.

Most of them seem to use a similar format for their markings, something along the lines of `###YWW` where `###` is some short code for the series, sometimes two, sometimes three characters, `Y` is the year code, and `WW` is the week code in the year of manufacture.

So what we are looking for is something with a part code beginning with `FA`, and possibly `FA=` but that seems a bit odd for a part number. A bit of searching led me to [this rather old](https://www.rom.by/files/Richtek_Marking_Code.PDF) document, which gives `FA` but for a completely different form factor which is a bit upsetting. However what it does show is part numbers that are `??=` - the very strange equals sign, which seemed like too much of a coincidence to ignore.

Some hunting around for Richtek SOT32-6 PWM controller images led me to this:

[image: Picture of PWM Controller with 1FA=### part number]
<sup>[Image Source](https://www.ebay.com/itm/183407975433)</sup>

Aha, we have a part marking of `|FA=S03` which is the same strange part number, but with a different year code. I've including the questionable `1` character which looks more like a `|` on this image, and may well be simply a pin 1 end marker (sometimes packages are marked with a line across the end which has pin 1 rather than a dot).

That gives us RICHPOWER (a.k.a. Richtek) [R7735GGE](https://www.richtek.com/Products/AC_DC/Flyback%20Controller/R7735?sc_lang=en&specid=R7735). Now the full [datasheet](https://usermanual.wiki/Document/r7735richtek.181378825/view) for that doesn't list the marking, it just says contact your local distributer, so I can't directly confirm my hunch, but it seems pretty solid from the anecdotal evidence.

From a pinout standpoint we have below, which matches sufficiently with the names in your comment:

```
1 - GND
2 - COMP (voltage feedback from opto coupler)
3 - PRO (optional external protection for overtemp or voltage)
4 - CS (current sense)
5 - VDD
6 - GATE (output to external FET)
```

Comment: p.s. That one was quite a fun challenge. Keep 'em coming.

Comment: Thank you sir for your hardwork & research but I think I am not that lucky. I am unable to find any distributor for Richtek in INDIA nor this part is available on mouser, digikey and element14. Anyway once again thanks for your research.